# change order of views in linear layout android

Tags: android, layout

As you know the order of views in linear layout is related to the order of them in xml file. Is it possible to change that order with java code by something like indexing?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I would try to remove all views with [`removeView(view)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#removeView%28android.view.View%29) and add them with [`addView(childView, index)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView%28android.view.View%29) in that order you like.

Answer (score 16):

[Remove the view](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#removeView%28android.view.View%29), then add it to its new position by calling [`addView (View child, int index)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView%28android.view.View,%20int%29), specifying the position at which to add the view.

Answer (score 2):

[`bringToFront()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#bringToFront()) may be useful, as it changes the order for order-dependent layouts, too

Comment: Perfect for swapping the order of two elements