# Shuffling existing Views

Tags: android

I would like to know how to move a view already defined in a layout file to a different position (index) within it's parent (programmatically of course).

For example, take this:

```
<LinearLayout>
    <RelativeLayout id="1"></RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout id="2"></RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout id="3"></RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout id="4"></RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And do this:

```
<LinearLayout>
    <RelativeLayout id="4"></RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout id="1"></RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout id="2"></RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout id="3"></RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I would like to achieve this at runtime and have the results reflect immediately if possible. If not, I'm ok with have it occur only on onCreate().

Comment: Do you want to achieve this on runtime?

Comment: @TamirAbutbul Yes!

Comment: have a look at my answer - i hope that it help you ever partly

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you can use "removeView(view)" for your view and add it in runtime with "addView" in the order that you would like , check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17776306/change-order-of-views-in-linear-layout-android).
I think that this is not the best solution if you look at performance but this is the best i could come with.

Comment: If another post already has the solution, then please flag the question as a duplicate, rather than posting an answer to point to another answer.