# How do I set layout parameters for Relative Layout?

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, android-layoutparams

I'm using Android Studio to create an app. The user will select a button from a list of three buttons which will take them to a new Activity named SurveyActivity. In SurveyActivity, there are a few relative layouts with content. But depending on which button to press, not all of the relative layouts will appear. The relative layouts are linked to each other because they're one under another.

The problem I have encountered is that when certain views are View.GONE, then you can't access the ID for the android:layout_below

I have already tried [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305395/how-to-lay-out-views-in-relativelayout-programmatically/2499721#2499721) but I don't seem to understand why you use layout params.

I know that if you use a LinearLayout you can do it, but I wanted to know if there was a way to do it this way with Relative Layouts.

Here is the SurveyActivity:

```
public class SurveyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

String timeOfDay;

private RelativeLayout relativeLayoutMentally, relativeLayoutPhysically, relativeLayoutEnergised,
        relativeLayoutMotivated, relativeLayoutAlert, relativeLayoutSatisfied, relativeLayoutCalm;



@Override
@TargetApi(17)
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_survey);
    // Initalisation

    relativeLayoutMentally = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.mentally);
    relativeLayoutPhysically = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.physically);
    relativeLayoutEnergised = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.energised);
    relativeLayoutMotivated = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.motivated);
    relativeLayoutAlert = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.alert);
    relativeLayoutSatisfied = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.satisfied);
    relativeLayoutCalm = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.calm);

    relativeLayoutMentally.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    relativeLayoutPhysically.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    relativeLayoutSatisfied.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    // Intent

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    timeOfDay = intent.getStringExtra("Time of Day");


    switch(timeOfDay){
        case "Morning":



            relativeLayoutEnergised.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        relativeLayoutMotivated.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        relativeLayoutAlert.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        relativeLayoutCalm.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            break;
        case "Afternoon":

            relativeLayoutEnergised.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            relativeLayoutMotivated.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            relativeLayoutAlert.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            relativeLayoutCalm.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            break;
        case "Evening":

            relativeLayoutEnergised.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            relativeLayoutMotivated.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            relativeLayoutAlert.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            relativeLayoutCalm.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            break;

    }

}
}
```

Here is the xml file of the survey:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.android.happinesssurvey.SurveyActivity">



        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/mentally"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <SeekBar
                    android:id="@+id/seekBarMentally"
                    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.SeekBar.Discrete"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/questionMentally"
                    android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
                    android:max="10"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:progress="5" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/questionMentally"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/question_mentally" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/label_mentally"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text=""/>


            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/physically"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <!--android:layout_below="@+id/mentally"-->

                <SeekBar
                    android:id="@+id/seekBarPhysically"
                    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.SeekBar.Discrete"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/questionPhysically"
                    android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
                    android:max="10"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:progress="5" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/questionPhysically"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/question_physically" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/label_physically"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text=""/>


            </RelativeLayout>


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/energised"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <!--android:layout_below="@id/physically">-->

            <SeekBar
                android:id="@+id/seekBarEnergised"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.SeekBar.Discrete"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/questionEnergised"
                android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
                android:max="10"
                android:padding="20dp"
                android:progress="5" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/questionEnergised"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/question_energised" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/questionEnergised"
                android:gravity="fill_horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="220dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="220dp"
                    android:text="@string/label_unenergised" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/label_energised" />

            </LinearLayout>


        </RelativeLayout>



        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/motivated"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <!--android:layout_below="@id/energised">-->

            <SeekBar
                android:id="@+id/seekBarMotivated"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.SeekBar.Discrete"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/questionMotivated"
                android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
                android:max="10"
                android:padding="20dp"
                android:progress="5" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/questionMotivated"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/question_motivated" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/questionMotivated"
                android:gravity="fill_horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="220dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="220dp"
                    android:text="@string/label_unmotivated" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/label_motivated" />

            </LinearLayout>


        </RelativeLayout>


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/satisfied"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <!--android:layout_below="@id/motivated">-->

            <SeekBar
                android:id="@+id/seekBarSatisfied"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.SeekBar.Discrete"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/questionSatisifed"
                android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
                android:max="10"
                android:padding="20dp"
                android:progress="5" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/questionSatisifed"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/question_satisifed" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/questionSatisifed"
                android:gravity="fill_horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="220dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="220dp"
                    android:text="@string/label_unsatisfied" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/label_satisfied" />

            </LinearLayout>


        </RelativeLayout>



        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/alert"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <!--android:layout_below="@id/satisfied">-->

            <SeekBar
                android:id="@+id/seekBarAlert"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.SeekBar.Discrete"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/questionAlert"
                android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
                android:max="10"
                android:padding="20dp"
                android:progress="5" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/questionAlert"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/question_alert" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/questionAlert"
                android:gravity="fill_horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="220dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="220dp"
                    android:text="@string/label_not_alert" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/label_alert" />

            </LinearLayout>


        </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/calm"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <!--android:layout_below="@id/alert">-->

                <SeekBar
                    android:id="@+id/seekBarCalm"
                    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.SeekBar.Discrete"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/questionCalm"
                    android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
                    android:max="10"
                    android:padding="20dp"
                    android:progress="5" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/questionCalm"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/question_calm" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/questionCalm"
                    android:gravity="fill_horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="220dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="220dp"
                        android:text="@string/label_not_calm" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="90dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/label_calm" />

                </LinearLayout>


            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

I expect that after I do it, some of the relative layouts will show up

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean you can't access the views below a view that is set to be `GONE`? Do you mean you can't click it or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set layout_below programatically, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3277302/6447661)

Regarding your case: `layout_below` will not work under LinearLayout as a parent.

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/mentally"
            ... >
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/physically"
            android:layout_below="@+id/mentally"
            ... >
```

Just remove `layout_below` and order it in a sequence you want. If you want to change the sequence, then take a look at:
[change order of views in linear layout android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17776306/change-order-of-views-in-linear-layout-android)