# How do I shift a View under another View in LinearLayout?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I cannot seem to find the right keywords for my question. Not to be confused with XML Layout editing, can I programmatically shift one `View` under another `View` in real-time inside a `LinearLayout` container?

Here is my main layout XML file. It is as easy as just dragging the two buttons to the UI editor and naming them:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 2" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Let's say I did something in my app and suddenly `button1` shifted below `button2` and `button2` went up. How can I make that happen? Does something like `my1Button.shiftDown();` or similar even exist?

Comment: You can simply set the visibility visible or gone programetically

Comment: You could do a `removeView` followed by an `addView` to specify the order, but depending on the effect you want you may be better off using a `RecyclerView`, as it has better support for dragging/dropping views

Comment: @RohitSuthar
Could you clarify, please?

@PPartisan
I don't care about effects. A simple insta-shift is fine, so I'm not gonna bother with `RecyclerView`.

Comment: In that case, you can follow the advice here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17776306/change-order-of-views-in-linear-layout-android

Comment: Whether you want to totally hide the button1 below the button2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to work with the children of the linear layout. Something like this:

```
public void reorderButtons() {
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_layout);

    View button1 = layout.getChildAt(0);
    View button2 = layout.getChildAt(1);

    // Remove both buttons
    layout.removeAllViews();

    // Add the buttons in the order you want
    layout.addView(button2);
    layout.addView(button1);
}
```

Comment: Better answer than the one in the thread which this one is marked as possible duplicate of.